# Trying to capture data from custom HTML on Elementor Forms/Wordpress through Webhook

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

My webhook is showing that it's being captured but will not display the email. It just shows "querystring" as the captured data.

I have this custom HTML block on elementor forms:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

and script:

```js
    document.getElementById('customForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

        const data = {
            name: name,
            email: email
        };

        const webhookUrl = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/15585298/3svwi9j/'; // Replace with your actual webhook URL

        fetch(webhookUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                alert('Data submitted successfully!');
                document.getElementById('customForm').reset(); // Clear the form
            } else {
                alert('Error submitting data.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
        });
    });
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" 
size="50%" style="padding:15px; margin:auto;">
```